# Google App Maker using dropdowns as filters with a table widget drilling down into the results

Tags: google-app-maker

I am building a page that contains a Table widget which is linked to my data source.  I have 3 drop downs on that page, which are associated with values in the data source columns.

When a selection from a drop down is made, it will query the data source and return the rows of data to the Table widget.  Once those rows are returned and displayed in the Table widget, if they select from another drop down, it will query those rows in the table, not the data source.

For example, drop down "A" lists Agencies, drop down "B" lists all the Project Statuses, and drop down "C" lists all Project Managers.  When the user opens the page in AppMaker, he/she are presented with an empty Table widget and the 3 drop downs.  If the user selects from drop down "A" the value of HR, the data source is queried and all the rows that have HR as their agency is returned.  Now, the Table widget lists those returned rows.  If the user now selects from drop down "B" the value of Open, it will query the displayed rows (not query the data source), and display only those rows with Agency = HR and Status = Open.  And if the user selects from drop down "C" the value of John Doe, as before, it will query the displayed rows (not query the data source), and display only those rows with Agency = HR, Status = Open, and Manager = John Doe.

I am guessing I may have to set up Calculated Models, but would love to see a sample app that already does this.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/appmaker/templates/project-tracker/ - there is very similar functionality in Project Tracker template. Project List sample can also be your friend: https://developers.google.com/appmaker/samples/project-list/

Comment: Used the Project Tracker's Dashboard Page and a few functions from the script libraries --- got it to work.  Great suggestion.